# I am seeing this build error, what could that mean?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to run my company's React.js project that I have downloaded from Tortoise SVN.

```
PS C:\Projects\Old EHR> yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next start
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
Error: Could not find a production build in the 'C:\Projects\Old EHR\.next' directory. Try building your app 
with 'next build' before starting the production server. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/production-start-no-build-id
    at NextNodeServer.getBuildId (C:\Projects\Old EHR\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:165:23)   
    at new Server (C:\Projects\Old EHR\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:56:29)
    at new NextNodeServer (C:\Projects\Old EHR\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:67:9)
    at NextServer.createServer (C:\Projects\Old EHR\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:144:16)
    at async C:\Projects\Old EHR\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:156:31
    at async NextServer.prepare (C:\Projects\Old EHR\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:131:24)
    at async C:\Projects\Old EHR\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-start.js:116:9
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Projects\Old EHR> yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
event - compiled client and server successfully in 722 ms (136 modules)
```

This is the error I am getting

I tried using all the dependencies and tried asking ChatGPT but I couldn't run the project.

Comment: You could start by reading the error message: "Try building your app 
with 'next build' before starting the production server." In any case, running `yarn dev` seems to have worked. What happens when you go to http://localhost:3000/?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking your coworkers about this...

Answer (score -1):

At the first you must install dependencies and then try to build project.

```
npm i
npm run build
npm start
```